# Where can I buy original edition and out-of-print roleplaying books and accessories?

Tags: books, games-industry

I know of a few online retailers that specialise in out-of-print (OOP), second-hand, and original editions of RPG books and accessories. Let's make a definitive list of them!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

eBay has always been my source.

Answer (score 11):

[Noble Knight Games](http://www.nobleknight.com/) carries OOP stuff, but the prices are premium, and things are not always in-stock.

Comment: Noble Night has excellent international service

Comment: What @Runeslinger said. Expensive, but reliable.

Comment: International postage is also quite expensive, but NK at least bundle items together.

Answer (score 8):

[The Acaeum (OOP collectors' site) has a valuable Classifieds board](http://www.acaeum.com/forum/viewforum.php?f=3).

And to a lesser extent, [Classifieds at Dragonsfoot.org](http://www.dragonsfoot.org/forums/viewforum.php?f=21).

Comment: Acaeum is a valuable resource to make sure you not being ripped off on the high value items.

Answer (score 8):

For used used books I usually start at [abebooks.com](http://abebooks.com) which is an aggregate collection of used booksellers across the country.

Here's the results for ['Dungeons & Dragons' first edition published by TSR before 1990](http://www.abebooks.com/servlet/SearchResults?bi=h&bx=off&ds=50&fe=on&kn=dungeons+%26+dragons&pn=TSR&recentlyadded=all&sortby=17&sts=t&x=0&y=0&yrh=1990).

Answer (score 8):

**[Alibris](http://www.alibris.com/)**

I bought them there because it was the cheapest place I could find my books. Surprisingly they arrived sooner than when I ordered some other books to Amazon. That was some time ago and I was at Mexico, but I keep this link as my favorite place for used books.

Comment: I once bought a "good" condition book from Alibris.  When I got it, I swear to you it was near-mint or mint.  It was also a good bit cheaper than the same book was on either Amazon (granted once a book goes out of print, some sellers get greedy), or on ebay.

Answer (score 6):

[Troll and Toad](http://trollandtoad.com/) is a second-hand and first-hand dealer that carries out-of-print and recent products.

Answer (score 4):

If you have any used book shops nearby give them a try. I've actually found quite a few original D&D and AD&D accessories at some in VA and MD.

Answer (score 4):

Within Ebay look for the CrazyEgor store. He specializes in want lists, so you can send him titles you're looking for. He'll keep your contact info if he doesn't have it on hand now, and let you know when it's available. He knows what his stuff is worth.

When you use ABEBOOKS.Com or Bookfinder.Com it pays to search loosely, as not all those offering second hand material bother to enter the entire author name, or check the spelling on titles. In "classic" format [look below the top screen], it will rank the books it finds in ascending order by price.

Answer (score 4):

[Ludik Bazar](http://www.ludikbazar.com/index.php?language=en)

It is a French store, but they have a lot of English material as well.

They have plenty of second hand books and they are also specialized in massive discount for discontinued games or bankrupted editors. (Lot's of brand new D&D3.5 and 4  books around 10€ for example). 
They are also dealing CCG and boardgame.

Very nice store for filling holes in collections and to find some second hand rarities.

I don't know the foreign delivery prices and conditions. Since there is an English version of the site I guess they are shipping abroad.

Comment: Having just used this, it gets an upvote! It's the only place I found a copy of *The Princes' Kingdom* for sale.

Comment: I'm glad this answer has been useful ! How easy are abroad shipping with the site ?

Comment: I won't be able to say for sure until it arrives, but the ordering process itself was easy enough.

Answer (score 3):

Amazon, stil has some 3.0/3.5 d&d material.

Answer (score 3):

[RPG Geek](http://rpggeek.com) is an RPG database, and the user features are mostly about listing your collection, but it's also useful for coordinating sales and trades. People can mark items in their collection for sale or trade, and you can add items to your "want to buy" or "want for trade" lists.

Answer (score 3):

I find that local [Half Price Books](http://www.hpb.com/) is an excellent source and I've also used [Paperback Swap](http://www.paperbackswap.com) to find a few books as well.

Answer (score 2):

[Sentry Box](http://www.sentrybox.com/) is pretty good.
Remember, the prices on amazon are WRONG.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this wrongness? Not disputing it—I'm curious what you mean.

Comment: Yeah, there are a lot of "vendors" that offer games for ridiculous prices on Amazon:
http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/1894525450/ref=pd_luc_mri?ie=UTF8&m=ASYDZOX0HKBSE
Not all of them mind you. but if the price is higher than you expected to pay, take the time to check another site.

Answer (score 2):

**The ASGI RPG Store (www.asgi.co.uk)** has a reasonable stock of items and I've bought a few things from there (1st Ed) with no problems - usually pretty quick delivery and response to e-mails.

Prices slightly higher than individual seller eBay auctions but lower than most of the eBay buy it nows, plus you don't have to wait for someone to list a particular item - it's just from stock.