# What vampire-focused rpgs exist besides those made by White Wolf?

Tags: game-recommendation

Just out of curiosity (not as if I wanted to run a game like this these days): Are there any *good* alternatives to *Vampire: The Requiem/Masquerade* that (instead of just making them available optionally, as Kult does, for example) *focus* on playing modern day vampires in a contemporary, occultish setting? (Please let's avoid D20-based games. Thank you.)

Comment: Would "modern day supernaturals in a contemporary, occultish setting" work, so long as vampires get real support? I'm thinking of games like the Dresden Files or NightLife — well, NightLife isn't *good*, but it's otherwise appropriate — where vampires are a spotlighted option but not the exclusive focus.

Comment: Related: [List of occult modern world settings](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/3903/8)

Comment: Jadasc: Thanks, but such games would count as "semi-answers" to the question. :) I know a lot of occult modern games myself - it's whether there's one about PC vampires that is *not* VtM/VtR that I missed... [Btw, thanks for the edit, it's better this way.]

Comment: @OpaCitiZen: No worries. I keep coming across games that have PC vampires but not *exclusively* PC vampires, or games about vampires where they aren't the PCs, like *Annalise*. The one exception I can think, I'm posting below.

Comment: @OpaCitiZen: The one I have in mind is Jared Sorensen's **Vampires**, which was eventually adapted into the **Monster Garage** game published in the *Requiem Chronicler's Guide*. Although it's derived from the WW games, it's not tied to the World of Darkness, and uses a slick reinterpretation to deconstruct the nature of playing as vampires. It's a little indie, and doesn't follow your rules strictly, but it's worth investigating. Presuming you were actually running a game like this, that is, which you say you're not. :)

Comment: Would **Dresden Files** work?  It's a modern setting and I think Vampires (of various Courts) are playable.

Comment: @okeefe Asked above. :) What the OP is looking for is a game "about" vampires in the same way that **Top Secret**, **Spookshow**, and **Spycraft** are "about" spies, but in very different ways.

Comment: Indeed, as Jadasc says, I wanted to know whether there were any other rpgs in which the players play (contemporary) vampires by default, and the whole world+system is built with that in focus. So far it seems like there are no serious contenders. We have a number of "you can also play vampires with this if you really want to" games, but nothing focused. I'm thankful for all the answers, nonetheless. :)

Answer (score 4):

Good alternatives? I don't know what you think is good! Try these:

- [GURPS Vampire: the Masquerade](http://sjgames.com/gurps/books/VampireTheMasquerade/)
- [Rifts Vampire Kingdoms](http://www.palladiumbooks.com/Merchant2/merchant.mvc?Screen=PROD&Store_Code=1001&Product_Code=802-E)
- [TORG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torg) has a vampire PC option

There are games that you could use to play vampires that aren't specifically vampire games. Try [Sorcerer](http://adept-press.com/role-playing-games/sorcerer/), for example.

I also think that [My Life with Master](http://www.halfmeme.com/master.html) would be a fantastic game for playing vampires. You'd have a Master who gave you orders and you could all be minion vampires doing awful things. You could struggle to keep your humanity as you did more and more terrible things.

Comment: A vampire-themed MLWM game would be fun.

Answer (score 3):

Vincent Baker's [Hungry, Desperate and Alone](http://web.archive.org/web/20030113062938/http://www.septemberquestion.org/lumpley/hungry.html) focusses on playing modern day vampires in a contemporary setting. It's a short game, just a blog post.

I don't know whether it's good. I imagine, given that it hasn't been formally released, that it's only half-baked: an interesting game, rather than a polished one.

At the least, though, it's packed with ideas you can use in other games.

Answer (score 2):

[Annalise](http://www.findannalise.com/Annalise) by Nathan Paoletta is a really interesting and playable take of vampires. Not a perfect fit for your specific need but a great game.

Comment: I've looked into Annalise; if I'm correct, you don't play the vampire in that one.

Comment: @Jadasc You *can* play vampires, but they'll somehow be in danger from The Vampire of the system. So, children of an elder vampire or something. It *could* do it, but not being designed to do it, that might not fit the OP criteria.

Answer (score 1):

Your question sparked a vague memory, and I went off looking for what I seemed to recall. I didn't find it, but I found two other things that might be of interest. I can't actually *recommend* any of them, as I haven't played them, so bear that in mind.

[Death's Shadow: The Book of Vampires](http://www.bardsandsages.com/karma) "combines the vampire mythos with the unique multiverse view of Karma system to bring Storytellers everything they allow their players to take on the roles of vampires"

[Nameless Streets](http://www.alephtargames.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&catid=40%3afantasy&id=57%3anameless-streets&Itemid=57) is a Heroquest-based game that includes the option of vampire PCs. It appears to be a sort of modern-day paranormal noir, if that makes any sense. Probably not focused enough on vampires to be useful.

Comment: Of those three, only the last satisfies all the requirements of the OP — the first is a game that's not exclusively about vampires, and the second is Modern OGL, which is a synonym for d20.

Comment: Thanks for spotting the OGL thing, Jadasc. I'm not a d20 gamer, so I didn't realise. I've taken it out. I will leave in Nameless Streets, however, as it *may* be able to meet the OP's requirements. although rereading the question, I see this is probably no better than Kult.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry just a link, because i have never played nor heard much of this RPG.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angel_(role-playing_game)

Comment: Although the lead character of the television show is a vampire, the **Angel** game isn't "about" vampires in a way that satisfies the question.

Comment: @Jadasc - However, I have run a *Buffy* game with vampire PCs - it works nicely. Never bothered with the *Angel* game though.

Comment: @gomad - Certainly. However, the OP asked for a game that was "focused" on vampires. I played a mummy in a **Bureau** 13 game using the BESM rules, but that doesn't make BESM a game about monsters. (*Cold Hands, Dark Hearts* notwithstanding.)

Comment: @Jadasc - Of course. And that's why I didn't +1 this answer or add an answer espousing the use of *Buffy* for this purpose. Comments have lower standards than answers, right?