# Purchasing old GURPS and other out of print games online

Tags: gurps, online-resources

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I buy original edition and out-of-print roleplaying books and accessories?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/2782/where-can-i-buy-original-edition-and-out-of-print-roleplaying-books-and-accessor)

Can anyone help me? I'm looking for some old GURPS games (and quite often I want to buy this or that out-of-print game), so I need some RPG shops that sell online. Best are shops in Europe; others are a little worse. I already know that eBay can help me 75% of the time. (I hope this isn't off-topic.)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie It's ok if you want to merge. The main difference is that I'm looking mainly for European shops, and in the other question the answers where mainly for USA shops.

Answer (score 15):

If you are looking for content, rather than specifically for dead tree, most of the OOP GURPS books are available in PDF from Warehouse 23. 
http://warehouse23.com/

The ones that aren't tend to be the licensed ones (Horseclans, Commonwealth, etc).

Noble Knight Games also tends to have lots of OOP stuff. 
http://www.nobleknight.com/Default.asp
Prices tend to run a bit higher than ebay.

Check American Book Exchange, as well: 
http://www.abebooks.com/
It's a clearinghouse for used book dealers to share their catalogs for comparison shopping. It will connect you with literally hundreds of bookstores

Comment: abebooks is very useful. It would be beautiful if it was present in other nations.

Comment: +1 for e23! It's absolutely the best resource for old GURPS and other SJG content.

Comment: Abebooks is available worldwide, and handles bookdealers from the whole world. I've changed the e23 address to its replacement, Warehouse23.

Answer (score 2):

For general "Random RPG" stuff, try [Crazy Egor](http://www.crazyegors.4t.com/). While he charges a premium and is in the states, he has a remarkably stupid inventory.

Answer (score 1):

I totally recommend http://www.fanen.com if you understand German. Excellent GURPS section (as well as many other treasure troves): http://www.fanen.com/rollenspiele/s--1_131_-1_-1/katalog/1909816707/gurps-4th-edition.html (and although the title says 4th edition it's much more).

Comment: Google Translate and Chrome are my friends :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'll add some RPG shops I know:

Collectors Point (Sweden)
http://www.collectorspoint.se/

Game Maniac (Sweden)
http://www.gamemaniacs.se/

I Giochi dei Grandi (Italy)
http://www.igiochideigrandi.it/

Dragon Store (Italy)
http://www.dragonstore.it/

Answer (score 0):

[Amazon.com](http://www.amazon.com) I've found to be quite good. Unfortunately if you're outside the US you don't get their super saver shipping, but usually you're ordering from a storefront anyway. I find the prices on the .com site to be much more reasonable than their regional sites (.ca is the other place I look, and this isn't just because of the exchange rate, as lately it's been close to 1:1).